# What are the best overviews for cloud technology?

Tags: cloud, cloud-platform

There has been a lot of buzz around cloud technologies. What resources would you recommend that review the cloud computing world, and helps one get the **big picture** and **current trends**?

In addition to reading these overviews, what would you recommend as first steps to get acquainted with these technologies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from [Microsoft Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/azure/default.mspx) mentioned by the others, there's also:

- [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)
- [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)
- [Sun Cloud Computing](http://www.sun.com/solutions/cloudcomputing/index.jsp)

..and a few others. Azure is in CTP and free until the fall. Google's App Engine is free, but to a limit, and so is Amazon EC2 last I heard.

The whole thing is still very much in development, so it could be hard to distill exactly where its headed. Microsoft has a lot of interesting videos of [PDC](https://sessions.microsoftpdc.com/public/timeline.aspx) and [MIX](http://live.visitmix.com/) sessions which illustrate their approach.

Also see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing) for extra information.

Answer (score 2):

I liked Berkeley's [Above the Clouds](http://d1smfj0g31qzek.cloudfront.net/abovetheclouds.pdf) whitepaper.  It has a concise but detailed discussion of the cost/benefit analysis of cloud computing and of the different types of cloud providers out there.

Answer (score 1):

I did some similar research recently, here is a link that gives a good comparison between the major providers:

http://cloudenterprise.info/2008/10/29/microsoft-azure-vs-amazon-google-and-vmware/

I also recommend checking out the "meta-providers" such as [RightScale](http://www.rightscale.com), who make managing your cloud a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Get familiar with Azure. There are lots of manuals and tutorials on it's website.

http://www.microsoft.com/azure/

Also watch online sessions from MIX 09 related to Azure:

http://sessions.visitmix.com/

Answer (score 0):

Azure CTP is available for free till year end. Check [this](http://www.microsoft.com/azure/register.mspx) link.

Answer (score 0):

I would always take a look at John M Willis's/Cote's writings/podcasts about clouds:

- http://www.johnmwillis.com/cloud-computing/cloud-favorites/
- http://www.johnmwillis.com/cloud-computing/cloud-cafe-30-what-is-a-cloud-from-the-beginning/

And maybe browse through "thinking out cloud":

- http://gevaperry.typepad.com/main/2009/01/what-is-a-cloud-first-define-a-table-the-furniture-kind-that-is.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found a related discussion on the best cloud computing books here:
http://highscalability.com/books-web-2-0-architectures-and-cloud-application-architectures

Check that out if you are looking for great books on cloud computing and cloud architecture.