# what is meant by cloud computing? give some examples

Tags: cloud, cloud-platform

what is meant by cloud computing? give some examples

Answer (score 6):

Cloud Computing is an overarching category. You've got at least 3 distinct segments in this evolving market:

**IaaS**: Infrastructure as a Service  e.g. Amazon EC2

**PaaS**: Platform as a Service e.g. Google AppEngine

**SaaS**: Software as a Service  e.g. Salesforce

There is an emergent category also:

**DaaS**: Database as a Service  e.g. Amazon RDS, Microsoft SQL

In short, Cloud Computing relates to computing resources available through the WEB. Of course some folks will disagree to some extent with this definition but it can't be all wrong :-)

Comment: There is also an interesting wiki mindmap on Cloud Computing: http://www.mindmeister.com/15936058/cloud-computing-players

Answer (score 3):

See [What are the best overviews for cloud technology?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697076/what-are-the-best-overviews-for-cloud-technology).

Answer (score 2):

[What is cloud computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing)?

Examples :

Check out [Windows Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/windowsazure/) and [Amazon s3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, cloud computing combines CPU virtualisation, software as a service, and utility computing.

Utility computing refers to treating computing services as a utility that can be delivered like you would deliver water or gas. Easy to turn on, turn off, or increase the flow. This was enabled by effective CPU virtualisation, and the tools to manage these virtual CPUs in a zero-touch manner. Add on top of that, software as a service, and you have cloud computing. Some services are very barebones such as Amazon S3 storage, and others are more complex like salesforce.com CRM.